# AVAssetWriterInput - add image with a specific duration

Tags: swift, image, video, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I am using these piece of code to create a timelapse movie with a collection of images.

https://github.com/acj/TimeLapseBuilder-Swift/blob/master/TimeLapseBuilder/TimeLapseBuilder.swift

So now I want to add a specific duration between the images. For example... every image should be showed for 3 seconds but the fps of the video should be still 30 fps.

Can somebody help me with this?

```
  videoWriterInput.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: media_queue) {
                    let fps: Int32 = 30
                    let frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, fps)
                    let currentProgress = Progress(totalUnitCount: Int64(self.photoURLs.count))

                    var frameCount: Int64 = 0
                    var remainingPhotoURLs = [String](self.photoURLs)

                    while videoWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData && !remainingPhotoURLs.isEmpty {
                        let nextPhotoURL = remainingPhotoURLs.remove(at: 0)
                        let lastFrameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount, fps)
                        let presentationTime = frameCount == 0 ? lastFrameTime : CMTimeAdd(lastFrameTime, frameDuration)

                        if !self.appendPixelBufferForImageAtURL(nextPhotoURL, pixelBufferAdaptor: pixelBufferAdaptor, presentationTime: presentationTime) {
                            error = NSError(
                                domain: kErrorDomain,
                                code: kFailedToAppendPixelBufferError,
                                userInfo: ["description": "AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdapter failed to append pixel buffer"]
                            )

                            break
                        }

                        frameCount += 1

                        currentProgress.completedUnitCount = frameCount
                        progress(currentProgress)
                    }

                    videoWriterInput.markAsFinished()
                    videoWriter.finishWriting {
                        if let error = error {
                            failure(error)
                        } else {
                            success(videoOutputURL)
                        }

                        self.videoWriter = nil
                    }
                }
            } else {
                error = NSError(
                    domain: kErrorDomain,
                    code: kFailedToStartAssetWriterError,
                    userInfo: ["description": "AVAssetWriter failed to start writing"]
                )
            }
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Change `frameDuration` to `CMTimeMake(3, 1)`, try to set fps with `AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey` key in your assetWriter properties.